# Can cryptographically secure randomness be used to implement one time pad?

Tags: encryption, symmetric, one-time-pad

if I use an one time pad key generated using a cryptographically secure random source like python's secret module , to encrypt a message, will the one time pad scheme be secure?

I think the entire security of one time pad scheme will depend on cryptographically secure random source, since such randomness is already used for iv , nonces  in modern cryptography , my one time pad should be secure enough right?

Comment: Secure maybe, but how does the recipient decipher? If that's by XOR with the key, how do they get the key?

Comment: I came across a password manager which claims to use One Time Pad for security. They store key and ask for password from user which is used to derive or generate passwords for multiple accounts. Sorry for bad english i dont know how to describe it is from here i read https://github.com/Anish-M-code/PyPass

Comment: Don't trust any encryption program with a short or otherwise memorable key (or master password) that promises security with the One Time Pad. That just can't be: absent other crypto, knowing plaintext/cipertext pairs (here, actual password/database entry) reveals some or all of the key (or master password), and enough of that allows to decipher other database entries into the real password.

Comment: @fgrieu the program described by OP uses master password as plaintext , generates random key unique for a given account , and program encrypts plaintext and random key using one time pad cipher to generate password for particular account. It looks secure

Answer (score 2):

No. One time pads have to be generated from a physical entropy sources like diodes, radioactivity, e.t.c. You are only creating a [stream cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher) if you use the secrets module as that draws upon an underlying cryptographically secure pseudo random generator.

This style of question appears over and over, so reading through those tagged with [OTP](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/otp) is a must.

> my one time pad should be secure enough right?

Most of the time yes. But there are those who believe in the virtues of [information theoretic security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information-theoretic_security) for extreme use cases. Also see [quantum key distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_key_distribution) for much more sophisticated models.

Comment: I think it's important that you specify that the output must be uniform random and debiased. While a diode may be useful for generating a random sequence, it might not be completely uniform (even if it is highly unpredictable), and thus wouldn't be good for an OTP. If you edit to clarify that, and also mention that OTPs provide no integrity guarantees (only confidentiality), I'll upvote.